# Accessing object created in different Window in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have created one window and declared 2 instances of my object, then I modified them and wanted to pass to another Window. My questions are:

- How would i do that ?
  (I can pass simple types such as string or int trough window constructor but passing my own object giving me an error (Inconsistent Accessibility parameter order is less accessible then method))
- Does it have any connection with dataContext ?

Can anybody explain to me how I can achieve that (in the simplest possible way)? What are the correct ways to do that ?
Here is part of my code (everything is in one namespace):

```
public partial class Main_window : Window
{
    Order myOrder = new Order();
    Menu menu = new Menu();

    public Main_window()
    {  InitializeComponent()  }
    private void OpenSecondWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            Second_Window SecondWindow = new Second_Window();
            Second.ShowDialog(); 
    }
}

// Second Window class
public partial class Second_Window : Window
{
  public Second_Window(Order someOrder)
    {   InitializeComponent();   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `Order` type, and any other type you intend to inject the `SecondWindow` with, is defined as a *public* class:

```
public class Order { ... }
```

A non-public type cannot be part of the signature of a public method or constructor.